# Different SQL Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to write SQL query in order to extract some data.

i have this data in my table:

```
ID  Store   Value
1    9921    NOK
2    9921    NOK1
3    9921    OK3
```

what i need is to get data from select query like this form:

```
9921         NOK,NOK1,OK3
```

Any help please ?

Comment: What database engine?  To do that on Apache Derby I had to write a user-defined aggregator that concatenated strings.  Then I could run `select store, uda(value) where store=9921`.

Comment: i'm using pure SQL server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go through this below example

[**Demo: [SQLFiddle]**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/349d3/5)

The SQL I used is as below,

```
SELECT
 store,
 STUFF(
     (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + value
      FROM SampleData
      WHERE store = a.store
      FOR XML PATH (''))
      , 1, 1, '')  AS CombineValues
FROM SampleData AS a
GROUP BY store
```

you will see your expected result as **"CombineValues"**

```
store   CombineValues
9921    NOK,NOK1,NOK2
```

Comment: This answer could do with including (all/the pertinent part of) the actual code. We frown on "link only" answers here, where it's not possible to make sense of the answer by just reading it.

Comment: come on, what's wrong here? I had the same difficulty once in my project and here is the answer, is it wrong solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [STUFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292662/sql-select-stuff):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Store,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + Value
              FROM Your_Table
              WHERE Store = 9921
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM Your_Table
```

Comment: Just so you're aware, the magical concatenation is achieved by the `FOR XML PATH('')` bit of that query. All that `STUFF` is doing is removing a leading comma. Referring to this as "using STUFF" is to hugely miss the point of how that query works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to accomplish your excepted output by using `COALESCE`;

Create a sample table for testing purpose

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData (id INT ,store INT ,value NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (1 ,9921 ,'NOK')
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (2 ,9921 ,'NOK1')
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (3 ,9921 ,'NOK2')
```

Create a Scalar-Valued Function

```
Alter FUNCTION fun_GetCombinedData 
(
  @store int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @CombineValue nvarchar(max)

SELECT @CombineValue = COALESCE(@CombineValue + ', ', '') + value 
FROM SampleData where store=@store

RETURN @CombineValue

END
GO
```

Final Query,

```
SELECT store
,dbo.fun_GetCombinedData(store) AS value
FROM SampleData
GROUP BY store
```

Expected Output:

```
store   |    value
------------------------
9921    |  NOK,NOK1,NOK2
```

This is one of the way to simplify your select query.

Answer (score 0):

Using T-SQL we can do it this way:

```
declare @store int = 9921, @values varchar(max) = ''

select @values = @values
     + case
         when @values = '' then ''
         else ','
       end + value
  from table_name
 where store = @store
 order by id

select @store, @values
```